# Call Enqueue function in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is the first time I am using Retrofit2 and I am repeatedly getting response.isSuccessful() == FALSE 
Here is my code :

```
public void checkLogin(final String username , final String password) {
        mAPIService.userLogIn(username,password).enqueue(new Callback<CheckUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CheckUser> call, retrofit2.Response<CheckUser> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body());
                    if(response.body().getSucces()) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivityTab.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                            /*Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "firstName : " + response.body().getUser().getFirstName() +
                                "lastName : " + response.body().getUser().getLastName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + "User not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR." + response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CheckUser> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API." + t.getCause());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Unable to submit post to API."+t.getCause(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

May someone help me to solve this
Thank you ^_^

Comment: please share the retrofit initialisation code and mApi service code

Comment: Does your **API** works properly in **Postman** ?

Comment: Also add the message() of the Response

Comment: HERE is the message of the response : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
                 <html><head>
                 <title>403 Forbidden</title>
                 </head><body>
                 <h1>Forbidden</h1>
                 <p>You don't have permission to access /apiV5/user/check.php
                 on this server.<br />
                 </p>
                 <hr>
                 <address>Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10 Server at 192.168.0.31 Port 80</address>
                 </body></html>

Comment: Your question is not complete. Please use [edit] link below the question body to add more information instead of comments or answer section. 1) Post error log. 2) Post [mcve] 3) What's the base URL for your application? 4) Ensure that API works properly before trying it with Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the APIservice interface

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("node/read.php")
    Call <NodeList> getNodes();

    @GET("data/read.php")
    //@FormUrlEncoded
    Call<DataList> getDatas();

    @POST("data/readByNode.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<DataList> getDatasByNode(
            @Field("node") String nodeName
    );

    //@POST("user/check.php")
    @POST("user/check.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<CheckUser> userLogIn(
                        @Field("username") String username,
                        @Field("password") String password
    );
    @POST("prediction/readDayPrediction.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Prediction> sendDifference(
            @Field("difference") Integer difference
    );
}
```

Here is the RetrofitClient Class :

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").setLenient().create();

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>
try to change baseUrl 
www.servername.com/
don't append /apiV5 to baseurl  but add it 
@Get("apiV5/user/check.php")
fun check()
</pre>`